# wp_insert_term created and set for first once only

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

i have two function first is working good to create category and set it in post the problem in the second function is create taxonomy but not set in post !!

```
function autoset_post_category(&$post, $category)
{
    if(empty($category)) return;
    $cat    = get_cat_ID($category);
    if(!$cat)
    {
        $cat    = wp_insert_term($category, 'category', array(
            'description' => ': ' . $category,
            'slug' => sanitize_title($category)
        ));
        $cat    = $cat['term_id'];
    }
    if($cat)
    {
        $post['post_category']  = array($cat);
    }
}
function autoset_post_author(&$post, $taxonomy)
{
    if(empty($taxonomy)) return;
    $cat    = get_term_by( 'id', 'author', $taxonomy);
    if(!$cat)
    {
        $cat    = wp_insert_term($taxonomy, 'author', array(
            'description' => ': ' . $taxonomy,
            'slug' => sanitize_title($taxonomy)
        ));
        $cat    = $cat['term_id'];


    }
    if($cat)
    {
        $post['tax_input']  = array( 'author' => array( $cat ) );

    }
}
```

Does anyone know what the problem is.
thanks .